# Making a Quadcopter Axis System in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am facing difficulties in making this type of quadcopter system in Tikz.
[image]

I want to generate this type of picture, since i am beginner, i don't know how to draw it in tikz. I am starting with this code [Aircraft Shapes](https://github.com/sisl/aircraftshapes). Kindly help me out here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. And asking someone to do it completely for you is usually not well received on TeX-SX.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!!!

Here is my version of the quadcopter. I use a `\pic` for the cylinders (motors) which is useful to place a lot of coordinates. Everything else is done with `\foreach` statements, except for the booms.

```tex
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,perspective}

\tikzset
{%
  pics/cylinder/.style n args={3}{% #1 = radius, #2 = height, #3 = angle
    code={%
      \draw[pic actions] (135:#1) arc (135:315:#1) --++ (0,0,#2) arc (315:135:#1) -- cycle;
      \draw[pic actions] (0,0,#2) circle (#1);
      \foreach\z in {0,1}
      {
        \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=\z*\h]
          \coordinate (-cen\z) at       (0,0);
          \coordinate (-ESE\z) at    (-#3:#1);
          \coordinate (-ENE\z) at     (#3:#1);
          \coordinate (-NNE\z) at  (90-#3:#1);
          \coordinate (-NNW\z) at  (90+#3:#1);
          \coordinate (-WNW\z) at (180-#3:#1);
          \coordinate (-WSW\z) at (180+#3:#1);
          \coordinate (-SSW\z) at (270-#3:#1);
          \coordinate (-SSE\z) at (270+#3:#1);
        \end{scope}
      }
    }},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[isometric view,line cap=round,line join=round]
% dimensions
\def\l{4}    % boom length
\def\R{1}    % body radius
\def\r{0.15} % motor radius
\def\h{0.3}  % boom and body height
\pgfmathsetmacro\A{asin(\r*sin(45)/\R)}
% paths to situate the coordinates
\foreach[count=\i]\j in {E,N,W,S}
  \pic[draw=none] (\j) at (90*\i-90:\l) {cylinder={\r}{\h}{45}};
\pic[draw=none] (O) {cylinder={\R}{\h}{\A}};
% rotations
\foreach[count=\i]\j in {-1,1,-1,1}
{
  \draw[dashed] (90*\i:\l) + (0,0,-\h) --++ (0,0,-7*\h);
  \begin{scope}[shift={(180-90*\i:\l)},canvas is xy plane at z=-4*\h,x=\j cm]
    \draw[red,-latex] (.7,0) arc (0:270:0.7) node [right] {$M_\i$};
  \end{scope}
}
% z-axis
\draw[-latex] (0,0,\h) --++ (0,0,-2)  node [below] {$z$};
% motors
\foreach\i in {E,N,W,S}
  \pic[fill=white,shift={(0,0,-\h)}] at (\i-cen0) {cylinder={\r}{2*\h}{45}};
% boom, east
\draw[fill=white] (E-SSW1) arc (225:135:\r) -- (O-ENE1) arc (\A:-\A:\R) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=white] (E-SSW1) -- (E-SSW0) -- (O-ESE0) -- (O-ESE1) -- cycle;
% boom, north
\draw[fill=white] (N-SSE1) arc (315:225:\r) -- (O-NNW1) arc (90+\A:90-\A:\R) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=white] (N-SSW1) -- (N-SSW0) -- (O-NNW0) -- (O-NNW1) -- cycle;
% frame
\pic[fill=white] {cylinder={\R}{\h}{\A}};
% boom, west
\draw[fill=white] (W-NNE1) arc (45:-45:\r) -- (O-WSW1) arc (180+\A:180-\A:\R) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=white] (W-SSE1) -- (W-SSE0) -- (O-WSW0) -- (O-WSW1) -- cycle;
% boom, south
\draw[fill=white] (S-NNW1) arc (135:45:\r) -- (O-SSE1) arc (270+\A:270-\A:\R) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=white] (S-NNW1) -- (S-NNW0) -- (O-SSW0) -- (O-SSW1) -- cycle;
% propellers
\foreach[count=\i]\j in {140,10,60,15}
{
  \begin{scope}[shift={(90*\i-90:\l)},rotate around z=\j,canvas is xy plane at z=\h]
    \draw[fill=gray!30] (0,0) sin  (0.5,0.1) cos  (1,0) sin  (0.5,-0.1) cos (0,0)
                              sin (-0.5,0.1) cos (-1,0) sin (-0.5,-0.1) cos (0,0);
    \fill (0,0) circle (0.05);
  \end{scope}
}
% forces
\foreach\i in {1,2,3,4}
  \draw[ultra thick,blue,-latex] (90*\i:\l) + (0,0,2*\h) --++ (0,0,6*\h) node [right] {$F_\i$};
% axes
\draw[-latex] (0,0,\h) --++ (1.5,0,0) node [yshift=3mm] {\strut$y$};
\draw[-latex] (0,0,\h) --++ (0,1.5,0) node [yshift=3mm] {\strut$x$};
\draw[dashed] (O-cen1) --++ (-3,-4,0) coordinate (O');
\draw[-latex] (O') --++ (0,1, 0) node [left]  {$N$};
\draw[-latex] (O') --++ (1,0, 0) node [right] {$E$};
\draw[-latex] (O') --++ (0,0,-1) node [below] {$D$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent. My sincere compliments

Comment: Thanks, @Sebastiano!!! ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Quadcopter Axis System in Tikz done with **Mathcha** Editor.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,457); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 457

%Straight Lines [id:da9026943928168321] 
\draw  [dash pattern={on 0.84pt off 2.51pt}]  (79.99,5.52) -- (79.99,119.17) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da839234693943983] 
\draw  [dash pattern={on 0.84pt off 2.51pt}]  (559.9,33.01) -- (559.9,146.66) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da1087876075622769] 
\draw  [dash pattern={on 0.84pt off 2.51pt}]  (53.25,258.24) -- (53.25,371.89) ;
%Shape: Ellipse [id:dp7572875309969542] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 255; green, 255; blue, 255 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (561.25,79.92) .. controls (562.89,76.72) and (586.01,85.29) .. (612.9,99.07) .. controls (639.79,112.84) and (660.26,126.59) .. (658.62,129.79) .. controls (656.99,132.98) and (633.86,124.41) .. (606.97,110.64) .. controls (580.08,96.86) and (559.61,83.11) .. (561.25,79.92) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Ellipse [id:dp3621974064796898] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 255; green, 255; blue, 255 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (463.88,30.05) .. controls (465.51,26.85) and (488.64,35.42) .. (515.53,49.2) .. controls (542.42,62.97) and (562.89,76.72) .. (561.25,79.92) .. controls (559.61,83.11) and (536.49,74.54) .. (509.6,60.77) .. controls (482.71,46.99) and (462.24,33.24) .. (463.88,30.05) -- cycle ;

%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp2823271895583528] 
\draw   (53.58,308.48) -- (303.82,194.76) -- (309.67,202.56) -- (59.43,316.28) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Ellipse [id:dp5273428375305598] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 255; green, 255; blue, 255 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (54.25,308.92) .. controls (55.89,305.72) and (79.01,314.29) .. (105.9,328.07) .. controls (132.79,341.84) and (153.26,355.59) .. (151.62,358.79) .. controls (149.99,361.98) and (126.86,353.41) .. (99.97,339.64) .. controls (73.08,325.86) and (52.61,312.11) .. (54.25,308.92) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Ellipse [id:dp0946700011393522] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 255; green, 255; blue, 255 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (-43.12,259.05) .. controls (-41.49,255.85) and (-18.36,264.42) .. (8.53,278.2) .. controls (35.42,291.97) and (55.89,305.72) .. (54.25,308.92) .. controls (52.61,312.11) and (29.49,303.54) .. (2.6,289.77) .. controls (-24.29,275.99) and (-44.76,262.24) .. (-43.12,259.05) -- cycle ;

%Flowchart: Stored Data [id:dp0003201317501160261] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 255; green, 255; blue, 255 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (47.32,319.9) -- (47.32,307.95) .. controls (47.32,309.21) and (49.98,310.23) .. (53.25,310.23) .. controls (56.52,310.23) and (59.18,309.21) .. (59.18,307.95) -- (59.18,319.9) .. controls (59.18,321.16) and (56.52,322.18) .. (53.25,322.18) .. controls (49.98,322.18) and (47.32,321.16) .. (47.32,319.9) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp9144059414738381] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 255; green, 255; blue, 255 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (46.1,307.92) .. controls (46.1,303.97) and (49.3,300.77) .. (53.25,300.77) .. controls (57.2,300.77) and (60.4,303.97) .. (60.4,307.92) .. controls (60.4,311.86) and (57.2,315.07) .. (53.25,315.07) .. controls (49.3,315.07) and (46.1,311.86) .. (46.1,307.92) -- cycle ;


%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp7728414987821433] 
\draw   (303.82,195.76) -- (554.06,82.04) -- (559.9,89.84) -- (309.67,203.56) -- cycle ;
%Flowchart: Stored Data [id:dp041652333899612426] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 255; green, 255; blue, 255 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (555.32,91.9) -- (555.32,79.95) .. controls (555.32,81.21) and (557.98,82.23) .. (561.25,82.23) .. controls (564.52,82.23) and (567.18,81.21) .. (567.18,79.95) -- (567.18,91.9) .. controls (567.18,93.16) and (564.52,94.18) .. (561.25,94.18) .. controls (557.98,94.18) and (555.32,93.16) .. (555.32,91.9) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp7818145303441153] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 255; green, 255; blue, 255 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (554.1,79.92) .. controls (554.1,75.97) and (557.3,72.77) .. (561.25,72.77) .. controls (565.2,72.77) and (568.4,75.97) .. (568.4,79.92) .. controls (568.4,83.86) and (565.2,87.07) .. (561.25,87.07) .. controls (557.3,87.07) and (554.1,83.86) .. (554.1,79.92) -- cycle ;

%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp2290805651060528] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 255; green, 255; blue, 255 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (84.66,43.62) -- (311.1,199.42) -- (307.43,208.46) -- (80.99,52.65) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Ellipse [id:dp6942686958610877] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 255; green, 255; blue, 255 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (82.1,47.72) .. controls (80.03,44.79) and (98.38,28.31) .. (123.08,10.91) .. controls (147.77,-6.49) and (169.47,-18.21) .. (171.54,-15.28) .. controls (173.61,-12.34) and (155.26,4.14) .. (130.56,21.54) .. controls (105.86,38.94) and (84.17,50.66) .. (82.1,47.72) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Ellipse [id:dp3856373921297922] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 255; green, 255; blue, 255 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (-7.34,110.72) .. controls (-9.41,107.79) and (8.94,91.31) .. (33.64,73.91) .. controls (58.33,56.51) and (80.03,44.79) .. (82.1,47.72) .. controls (84.17,50.66) and (65.82,67.14) .. (41.12,84.54) .. controls (16.42,101.93) and (-5.27,113.66) .. (-7.34,110.72) -- cycle ;
%Flowchart: Stored Data [id:dp135842864985791] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 255; green, 255; blue, 255 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (73.36,56.54) -- (73.51,44.59) .. controls (73.5,45.85) and (76.14,46.9) .. (79.41,46.94) .. controls (82.68,46.98) and (85.35,46) .. (85.36,44.74) -- (85.21,56.69) .. controls (85.19,57.95) and (82.53,58.93) .. (79.26,58.89) .. controls (75.98,58.85) and (73.34,57.8) .. (73.36,56.54) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp5184791926773] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 255; green, 255; blue, 255 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (72.29,44.54) .. controls (72.34,40.59) and (75.58,37.43) .. (79.53,37.48) .. controls (83.48,37.53) and (86.64,40.77) .. (86.59,44.72) .. controls (86.54,48.67) and (83.3,51.83) .. (79.35,51.78) .. controls (75.4,51.73) and (72.24,48.49) .. (72.29,44.54) -- cycle ;

%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp538607544170224] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 255; green, 255; blue, 255 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (303.82,194.76) -- (530.26,350.56) -- (526.59,359.59) -- (300.15,203.79) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Ellipse [id:dp21517649092307467] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 255; green, 255; blue, 255 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (255.24,196.76) .. controls (255.24,185.29) and (276.99,176) .. (303.82,176) .. controls (330.65,176) and (352.4,185.29) .. (352.4,196.76) .. controls (352.4,208.23) and (330.65,217.52) .. (303.82,217.52) .. controls (276.99,217.52) and (255.24,208.23) .. (255.24,196.76) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da2953316294980599] 
\draw    (305.4,199.52) -- (221.89,143.2) ;
\draw [shift={(219.4,141.52)}, rotate = 34] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [id:da5906523993990767] 
\draw    (305.4,199.52) -- (384.65,164.73) ;
\draw [shift={(387.4,163.52)}, rotate = 156.3] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [id:da8288900870206617] 
\draw  [dash pattern={on 0.84pt off 2.51pt}]  (305.4,199.52) -- (355.4,347.52) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da5524007472746157] 
\draw    (355.4,347.52) -- (355.4,434.52) ;
\draw [shift={(355.4,437.52)}, rotate = 270] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [id:da6783455165748054] 
\draw    (355.4,347.52) -- (421.71,314.85) ;
\draw [shift={(424.4,313.52)}, rotate = 153.77] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [id:da1762006511105485] 
\draw    (355.4,347.52) -- (275.23,319.51) ;
\draw [shift={(272.4,318.52)}, rotate = 19.26] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
%Shape: Ellipse [id:dp4677546900293663] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 255; green, 255; blue, 255 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (531.18,353.72) .. controls (529.12,350.79) and (547.46,334.31) .. (572.16,316.91) .. controls (596.86,299.51) and (618.56,287.79) .. (620.62,290.72) .. controls (622.69,293.66) and (604.34,310.14) .. (579.65,327.54) .. controls (554.95,344.94) and (533.25,356.66) .. (531.18,353.72) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Ellipse [id:dp5123617593385752] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 255; green, 255; blue, 255 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (441.74,416.72) .. controls (439.68,413.79) and (458.02,397.31) .. (482.72,379.91) .. controls (507.42,362.51) and (529.12,350.79) .. (531.18,353.72) .. controls (533.25,356.66) and (514.9,373.14) .. (490.21,390.54) .. controls (465.51,407.93) and (443.81,419.66) .. (441.74,416.72) -- cycle ;
%Flowchart: Stored Data [id:dp124865266494953] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 255; green, 255; blue, 255 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (522.44,362.54) -- (522.59,350.59) .. controls (522.58,351.85) and (525.22,352.9) .. (528.49,352.94) .. controls (531.76,352.98) and (534.43,352) .. (534.45,350.74) -- (534.29,362.69) .. controls (534.28,363.95) and (531.61,364.93) .. (528.34,364.89) .. controls (525.07,364.85) and (522.43,363.8) .. (522.44,362.54) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp25852994708512766] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 255; green, 255; blue, 255 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (521.37,350.54) .. controls (521.42,346.59) and (524.66,343.43) .. (528.61,343.48) .. controls (532.56,343.53) and (535.72,346.77) .. (535.67,350.72) .. controls (535.62,354.67) and (532.38,357.83) .. (528.43,357.78) .. controls (524.48,357.73) and (521.32,354.49) .. (521.37,350.54) -- cycle ;


%Straight Lines [id:da9451385653971158] 
\draw    (305.4,199.52) -- (305.4,286.52) ;
\draw [shift={(305.4,289.52)}, rotate = 270] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
%Shape: Arc [id:dp6425093267399156] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0] (82.5,91.15) .. controls (81.67,91.16) and (80.83,91.17) .. (79.99,91.17) .. controls (65.9,91.17) and (54.49,88.82) .. (54.49,85.91) .. controls (54.49,83.01) and (65.9,80.65) .. (79.99,80.65) .. controls (94.07,80.65) and (105.49,83.01) .. (105.49,85.91) .. controls (105.49,88.25) and (98.11,90.23) .. (87.9,90.91) -- (79.99,85.91) -- cycle ; \draw    (82.5,91.15) .. controls (81.67,91.16) and (80.83,91.17) .. (79.99,91.17) .. controls (65.9,91.17) and (54.49,88.82) .. (54.49,85.91) .. controls (54.49,83.01) and (65.9,80.65) .. (79.99,80.65) .. controls (94.07,80.65) and (105.49,83.01) .. (105.49,85.91) .. controls (105.49,88.01) and (99.51,89.83) .. (90.88,90.67) ; \draw [shift={(87.9,90.91)}, rotate = 344.56] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (10.72,-5.15) -- (0,0) -- (10.72,5.15) -- (7.12,0) -- cycle    ; 
%Right Arrow [id:dp14983472860010894] 
\draw   (78.1,32.26) -- (78.1,-14.48) -- (68.74,-14.48) -- (80.07,-37.74) -- (91.4,-14.48) -- (82.04,-14.48) -- (82.04,32.26) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Arc [id:dp12262071830624155] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0] (567.36,106.02) .. controls (576.81,106.79) and (583.49,108.69) .. (583.49,110.91) .. controls (583.49,113.82) and (572.07,116.17) .. (557.99,116.17) .. controls (543.9,116.17) and (532.49,113.82) .. (532.49,110.91) .. controls (532.49,108.01) and (543.9,105.65) .. (557.99,105.65) .. controls (558.23,105.65) and (558.46,105.65) .. (558.7,105.65) -- (557.99,110.91) -- cycle ; \draw    (570.37,106.31) .. controls (578.19,107.21) and (583.49,108.93) .. (583.49,110.91) .. controls (583.49,113.82) and (572.07,116.17) .. (557.99,116.17) .. controls (543.9,116.17) and (532.49,113.82) .. (532.49,110.91) .. controls (532.49,108.01) and (543.9,105.65) .. (557.99,105.65) .. controls (558.23,105.65) and (558.46,105.65) .. (558.7,105.65) ;  \draw [shift={(567.36,106.02)}, rotate = 8.9] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (10.72,-5.15) -- (0,0) -- (10.72,5.15) -- (7.12,0) -- cycle    ;
%Right Arrow [id:dp3824400827244223] 
\draw   (558.31,65.83) -- (558.31,19.09) -- (548.95,19.09) -- (560.28,-4.17) -- (571.61,19.09) -- (562.25,19.09) -- (562.25,65.83) -- cycle ;
%Right Arrow [id:dp871569581353923] 
\draw   (51.31,292.83) -- (51.31,246.09) -- (41.95,246.09) -- (53.28,222.83) -- (64.61,246.09) -- (55.25,246.09) -- (55.25,292.83) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Arc [id:dp7690331234290071] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0] (61.36,339.02) .. controls (70.81,339.79) and (77.49,341.69) .. (77.49,343.91) .. controls (77.49,346.82) and (66.07,349.17) .. (51.99,349.17) .. controls (37.9,349.17) and (26.49,346.82) .. (26.49,343.91) .. controls (26.49,341.01) and (37.9,338.65) .. (51.99,338.65) .. controls (52.23,338.65) and (52.46,338.65) .. (52.7,338.65) -- (51.99,343.91) -- cycle ; \draw    (64.37,339.31) .. controls (72.19,340.21) and (77.49,341.93) .. (77.49,343.91) .. controls (77.49,346.82) and (66.07,349.17) .. (51.99,349.17) .. controls (37.9,349.17) and (26.49,346.82) .. (26.49,343.91) .. controls (26.49,341.01) and (37.9,338.65) .. (51.99,338.65) .. controls (52.23,338.65) and (52.46,338.65) .. (52.7,338.65) ;  \draw [shift={(61.36,339.02)}, rotate = 8.9] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (10.72,-5.15) -- (0,0) -- (10.72,5.15) -- (7.12,0) -- cycle    ;
%Shape: Arc [id:dp6673925984894136] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0] (529.5,395.15) .. controls (528.67,395.16) and (527.83,395.17) .. (526.99,395.17) .. controls (512.9,395.17) and (501.49,392.82) .. (501.49,389.91) .. controls (501.49,387.01) and (512.9,384.65) .. (526.99,384.65) .. controls (541.07,384.65) and (552.49,387.01) .. (552.49,389.91) .. controls (552.49,392.25) and (545.11,394.23) .. (534.9,394.91) -- (526.99,389.91) -- cycle ; \draw    (529.5,395.15) .. controls (528.67,395.16) and (527.83,395.17) .. (526.99,395.17) .. controls (512.9,395.17) and (501.49,392.82) .. (501.49,389.91) .. controls (501.49,387.01) and (512.9,384.65) .. (526.99,384.65) .. controls (541.07,384.65) and (552.49,387.01) .. (552.49,389.91) .. controls (552.49,392.01) and (546.51,393.83) .. (537.88,394.67) ; \draw [shift={(534.9,394.91)}, rotate = 344.56] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (10.72,-5.15) -- (0,0) -- (10.72,5.15) -- (7.12,0) -- cycle    ; 
%Straight Lines [id:da18313597256456715] 
\draw  [dash pattern={on 0.84pt off 2.51pt}]  (528.52,293.8) -- (528.52,407.45) ;
%Right Arrow [id:dp9523483907355541] 
\draw   (526.52,340.54) -- (526.52,293.8) -- (517.16,293.8) -- (528.49,270.54) -- (539.82,293.8) -- (530.46,293.8) -- (530.46,340.54) -- cycle ;

% Text Node
\draw (51,12.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$F_{1}$};
% Text Node
\draw (290,237.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$Z$};
% Text Node
\draw (299,335.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$N$};
% Text Node
\draw (391.9,333.92) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$E$};
% Text Node
\draw (361.9,413.92) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$D$};
% Text Node
\draw (219,116.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$X$};
% Text Node
\draw (367,132.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$Y$};
% Text Node
\draw (413,120.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$l$};
% Text Node
\draw (156,238.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$l$};
% Text Node
\draw (192,94.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$l$};
% Text Node
\draw (441,264.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$l$};
% Text Node
\draw (532,31.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$F_{2}$};
% Text Node
\draw (27,262.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$F_{3}$};
% Text Node
\draw (46,95.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$M_{1}$};
% Text Node
\draw (529,121.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$M_{2}$};
% Text Node
\draw (501,301.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$F_{4}$};
% Text Node
\draw (39,373.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$M_{3}$};
% Text Node
\draw (517,406.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$M_{4}$};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```