# Can it be reproduced by latex? If not, suggest a method

Tags: tikz-pgf

Can it be reproduced by latex? If not, suggest a method.
[image]

Comment: Sure it can. However, the water details may be easier to achieve with a drawing tool, like inkscape. Once you have a .svg, you can display it via tikz as well.

Comment: Okay, would you help to plot the paddles? I am trying to get the water details by inkscape

Comment: Perhaps this could be a starting point: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/637627/making-a-quadcopter-axis-system-in-tikz?

Comment: @JuanCastaño It is a superb help. I shall try with this.

Comment: If you are not a tikz expert, it will be a lot easier use Inkscape not only for reproduce the water details. Make the complete draw in this program, save  it as SVG but also as a PDF file, and then use the PDF with `\includegraphics` as with any image. If you later need modify the draw, edit the SVG version and overwrite the  PDF file (since importing the PDF to modify it directly could mean lost some detail).

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node {\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{c2YtW}};
  \node [fill=white,anchor=north east, inner sep=2.5pt, outer sep=2.6pt] at (current bounding box.north) {$\mathbf{n}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No, I want to reproduce the paddles. Not want to use it in includegraphics

Comment: @user1942348 in that case, https://www.tug.org/consultants.html

Comment: ^ this. Please understand that this website is about answering specific and detailed questions about Tex and related subjects. Your question seems to have a "draw this for me" component to which only professionals can answer.